# How to modify dynamically generated elements with Jquery and without using click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the dynamically created element:

```
<th style="" data-field="realName">
  <div class="th-inner ">Name</div>
  <div class="fht-cell"></div>
</th>
```

And I want to add the following attribute to it:

```
$("th[data-field='realName']").attr("data-i18n", "realName");
$("th[data-field='realName']").i18n();
```

I tried this:

```
$(document).on("trigger", "th[data-field='realName']", function (e) {
   $("th[data-field='realName']").attr("data-i18n", "realName");
   $("th[data-field='realName']").i18n();
})
```

But it didn't work---the attribute wasn't assigned.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How can you unequally identify this element? How are you creating this element and why can't add this attribute when creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use querySelector/querySelectorAll instead of jquery.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(th[data-field='realName']);
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].setAttribute("data-i18n", "realName");
}
```

or

```
var element = document.querySelector(th[data-field='realName']);
if(element)
    element.setAttribute("data-i18n", "realName");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code should be like this:

```
$("th").each(function(){
  if ($(this).data("field") == "realName"){
    $(this).attr("data-i18n","realName");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(element).attr("data-x")` and `$(element).data("x")` are different.

[jQuery api : .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

try this:

```
 $("th[data-field='realName']").data("i18n", "realName");
   $("th[data-field='realName']").data("i18n");
```

Comment: Actually its more efficient to use attr() then data(), because if you use attr(). then you can access it via data(), but vice versa is not possible...